# How can I use relative paths in my manifest.json file for a PWA?

Tags: vue.js, progressive-web-apps, vite, manifest.json, web-app-manifest

I have built a web application using Vite + Vue and I want it to be installable as a mobile application. By adding a manifest.json file, with the proper config, my web application should be treated as a **Progressive Web App** and could be installed in all sorts of devices. I have created a basic `manifest.json` this way, following [this guide](https://web.dev/learn/pwa/web-app-manifest/).

```json
{
    "name": "My app",
    "short_name": "My app",
    "start_url": "/",
    "display": "standalone",
    "background_color": "#ffffff",
    "theme_color": "#ffffff",
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "/img/pwa_logo.png",
            "sizes": "512x512"
        }
    ]
}
```

This works fine when developing locally, but when building the app and deploying it, both the `start_url` and the `src` for the `icon` seems to be invalid.

The only solution that I came up with is to put the specific url in `start_url` and `src`. However this is not a great solution because I have several environments, and I would have to specify 3 different urls, and create 3 different `manifest.json`, one for each environment.

It also does not make sense because in every documentation I have seen about web app manifests, they specify the `start_url` as `"/"`, not hardcoded ones.

Hope anyone can help me figure out a solution to not have 3 different manifest files, and hardcoded urls.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

2 issues in your manifest:

- An icons property that includes a 192x192 px and a 512x512 px icon.
- A prefer_related_applications property set to a value other than true.

You can try to use chrome Lighthouse in DevTools to check your pwa `manifest.json`.

For more information, you can see [lighthouse-guide](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/lighthouse/pwa/installable-manifest/?utm_source=lighthouse&utm_medium=devtools) and [mdn-guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest)